# DB to PHP to JSON

Tags: php, json

Could you help me figure out why my code retrieves double data? I have put a DB on WAMP together with PHP file with query

```
<?php
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "//proba//database.accdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file." . $dbName);
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM Hotel";

$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch();


 echo json_encode($row);
```

Everything gets read fine, however I get double data, one with indexes 0,1,2,3 and other with indexes as names of DB fields

```
{ "0" : "1",
  "1" : "Hotel one",
  "2" : "3 stars",
  "3" : "5",
  "ID" : "1",
  "Category" : "3 stars",
  "Object" : "Hotel one",
  "Rating" : "5"
}
```

Comment: Like most questions on SO this one too can easily be resolved by just reading the manual.

Comment: Alternatively: Like so many PHP questions on SO, the problem in this one can be attributed to the crappiness of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of PDO fetch mode, use: `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to get only db fields.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch()` method returns an array that contains column data associated to their name, and also associated to their index order.

Use `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to get only data with column name, or `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` to get data with index numbers.